# how to update my feature branch from master after remote master was changed?

Tags: git, atlassian-sourcetree

Here is my situation

just pulled the changes from remote master, but my feature branch was created before, how can i make my feature branch working copy update as new as the master in sourcetree?

Comment: `$ git checkout yourFeatureBranch && git merge master` is what you're looking for. In SourceTree there must be a "merge" feature to do it, and you want to merge `master` to `yourFefatureBranch`.

Answer (score 0):

There are two options - `git rebase` and `git merge`. If the feature branch is a task branch you use privately, I would use something like `git rebase -i master`. Highly recommend you read this post to learn about the when to use rebase vs merge:

https://www.atlassian.com/git/tutorials/merging-vs-rebasing

Answer (score 0):

Two ways to solve the problem.

## Method 1

That is mentioned by @Kleskowy, merge the latest master into your feature branch.

## Method 2

If the master has lot of changes, then you can do like this,

```
git checkout master
git merge feature_branch
solve your conflicts at master branch
```

Method1 and Method2 are not the big difference, you can do it either way.

NOTE:  Merge with master will create the additional one commit.

## Method 3

If you want to be geekier, then go for rebase.

```
git checkout your_feature_branch
git rebase master
git checkout master
git merge your_feature_branch //If you have conflicts solve it.
git push origin master
```